# Create job for every testsuite using job dsl

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using TestNG, Jenkins, and the job-dsl-plugin.

I have a lot of TestNG XML testsuites for the tests in my project. What I want is a script that will go through each of these suites and create a job for them.

My test suites are formatted like this:

```
<suite name="Name of Suite">
    <test name="Name of Test">
        <packages>
            <package name="package.to.test.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So the job DSL script would have to recursively go through each of the tests in my testsuites directory, grab and parse the XML of these files, and then create a job for each one of them.

1. Visit repo
2. Recursively read every XML file in testsuites directory

   1. Grab the name of the suite -> name of Jenkins job
   2. Grab the path to this testsuite -> `-Dtestngfile=<path>`
3. Create a job for each of these

Comment: You described your problem, but you did not ask a question. Edit your text so that it contains a question.

Comment: @daspilker isn't it obvious enough that I'm just looking for a way to do this? Why is it necessary that I add "how do I accomplish this?"